# Finding k in a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

The equation in x

$3x^4 - 16x^3+18x^2+k=0$

has real solutions when.....

I need to find when this equation has four real solutions. I've tried

$x^2(3x^2-16x+18) +k=0$

and using $b^2-4ac$

$256-216 = 40$

I don't know where to go from here....

Comment: Just to get a feel for the polynomial, i would plot in integer values for k and look at the solutions (e.g. using wolfram alpha,). Pluging this into wolfram/or manually calculating the general solution using Ferraris formulas, will show that $$-k^3+22k^2+135k \geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Given $$3x^4-16x^3+18x^2+k=0\Rightarrow 3x^4-16x^3+18x^2 = -k$$

Now Let $$f(x) = 3x^4-16x^3+18x^2 = -k$$

So we will draw the graph of $f(x) = 3x^4-16x^3+18x^2$ and $f(x)=-k$

Now for Skeching graph of $$\displaystyle f(x) = 3x^4-16x^3+18x^2 $$

Now Using Second Derivative test.

$$f'(x) = 12x^3-48x^2+36x=12x(x^2-4x+3) = 12x(x-1)(x-3)$$

Now for Max. and Min., Put $f'(x) =0$

So we get $x=0,1,3$

Now $$f''(x) = 36x^2-96x+36 = 12(3x^2-8x+3)$$

Now at $x=0;,$ We get $f''(0) = 36>0$

So $x=0$ is a point of local Minimum

Now at $x=1;,$ We get $f''(1) = -24<0$

So $x=1$ is a point of local Maximum

Now at $x=3;,$ We get $f''(3)>0$

So $x=3$ is a point of local Minimum

So The graph of the function is like this.

[image]

So we get $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 5$

So for $4$ real solution  line $f(x)=-k$ intersect the graph of $f(x)=0$ at exactly $4$ points

So from graph $0<-k<5\Rightarrow -5 <k<0\Rightarrow k\in (-5,0)$

Comment: How did you know local maximum is 0 instead of 3?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post.

Comment: sorry I'm still a little confused - why did you not plug 3 into the original function? Why is that not considered for the range?

Comment: bcz in $f(3)$ to $f(0)$ line $f(x)=-k$  cut the graph exactly at $2$ point. But here we want $4$ Intersection points, Thats why we will not consider it.

Answer (score 0):

We want to know the values attained by $$f(x)=3x^4-16x^3+18x^2$$ exactly $4$ times.

To do this, consider the first derivative $$f'(x)=12x^3-48x^2+36x=12x(x^2-4x+3)=12x(x-1)(x-3)$$

The function $f$ has a local maximum in $x=1$ and a global minimum in $x=3$. Since $f(1)=5$ and $f(3)=-27$ the values we're interested in are $[0,5]$, or rather $[-5,0]$ (since we want to solve $f(x)=-k$ and not $f(x)=k$).

Comment: very good, however I was 2 min earlier...

Answer (score -1):

The answer is $k\in (-5,0)$. Critical points are comming from the square root $\sqrt{-k^3 + 22 k^2 + 135 k}=0$ which gives $-5,0,27$ as suspicious points. Then you check in between them and find the unique interval. You can also find the suspicious points from the inverse function theorem - find the values of $k(x)$ where $k'(x)=0$.